# Is it possible to generalize a result of Wang?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra, projective-modules

Assume $A$ and $B$ are commutative algebras with $1$.
There is a nice result of Wang, [Corollary 8](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869380902331/1-s2.0-0021869380902331-main.pdf?_tid=3e25ad1a-3e2d-11e5-b1dc-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1439080154_a8c7a76b2c7c860d578180ec8a516365), which says the following: "Let $B = A[z] = A[Z]/(h(Z))$. Then $B$ is a separable algebra over $A$ if and only if $h'(z)$, the formal derivative of $h$ evaluated at $z$, is a unit of $B$".

By definition, an $A$-algebra $B$ is separable over $A$ if $B$ is a projective $B \otimes_A B$-module via $\mu: B\otimes_A B \to B$, $b_1 \otimes_A b_2 \mapsto b_1b_2$.
In other words, $B$ is separable over $A$ if $pd_{B\otimes_A B}(B)=0$.

Hence Corollary 8 says: Let $B = A[z] = A[Z]/(h(Z))$. Then $pd_{B\otimes_A B}(B)=0$ if and only if the ideal of $B$ generated by $h'(z)$ is $B$.

**My question:** Can one generalize Corollary 8 to the following: Let $B = A[z] = A[Z]/(h(Z))$. Then $pd_{B \otimes_A B}(B) = n$ if and only if the ideal of $B$ generated by $h'(z),h''(z), \ldots, h^{(n+1)}$ is $B$.

(Remark: Maybe one should look at $n=1$ first).

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: The only possible values of $pd_{B\otimes_A B}(B)$ for such an algebra are 0, 1 and $\infty$, at least in the noetherian case.

Comment: Thanks!! very interesting. Please any hint how to show that $0,1$ and $\infty$ are the only possible values? (when $A$ is noetherian). Maybe I know how to show this in case $A=k[x,y]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to expect the higher derivatives of $h$ to be important.  For a simple counterexample to your conjecture, consider $h(Z)=Z^2$ (for, say, $A$ a field of characteristic $\neq2$).  Then $h''$ is a unit, but $B$ has infinite projective dimension over $B\otimes_A B$.  Another counterexample is $h(Z)=0$; then no number of iterated derivatives of $h$ can generate a nonzero ideal but the projective dimension of $B$ is $1$.

Comment: Thanks, nice. Do you think there exists a condition 'C' such that: The projective dimension of $B$ over $B \otimes_A B$ is finite if and only if condition C is satisfied?